# Keyboard "@ "symbol not working . Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: keyboard, 13.10

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.10, and updates it regularly. But I noticed from the start that I cannot type "<kbd>@</kbd>" symbol. I use a Toshiba Satellite C640 with i3 processor laptop.

The number keys on the lap work fine . But all the symbols that one can access by pressing <kbd>shift</kbd> are randomised. and I cannot find '<kbd>@</kbd>' symbol.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably chose your keyboard region wrong:

Settings → Region & Language → Input Source

Answer (score 5):

You should look at your **Keyboard Layout Chart**:

[image: Keyboard Layout Chart]

If this is, for example, **English (UK)**, you should use the following keys:

[image]

Also, if you want, you can change your **Keyboard layout** if you go to **Text Entry Settings...**

Comment: Thanks a lot... It worked.I can't believe it was such a tiny mistake from my part. Thanks a ton ...

Answer (score 0):

Go to System settings → Select Keyboard option → Click on Text Entry → Select the option English(US) from input sources.

Thats all. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced such a problem and solved it like this
Go to System Settings -> Region & Language -> Manage Installed Languages